# Jelastic- Host '' is not allowed to connect to MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, cloud, jelastic

I have created a new environment in Jelastic using Glassfish 3.1 and MySQL 5.5.32. I am trying to make connection to MySQL server from a local client computer using ./mysql -u root -p*** -h https://mysql-env-XXXXXXX.jelastic.servint.net however I receive the following error: ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '120.150.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server. I tried different username and password with different privileges.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set remote connection to MySQL server.
For this you should have Public IP enabled for your database. 
Please, consider the following documentation article: [Remote Access to MySQL](http://jelastic.com/docs/remote-access-mysql)